# Verify that the given functions are solutions to the corresponding homogenous equation $t^2y'' - 2y = 3t^2 - 1 | y_1(t) = t^2, y_2(t) = t^{-1}$

Tags: differential, homogeneous-equation

"verify that the given functions y1 and y2 satisfy the corresponding
homogeneous equation"

$t^2y'' - 2y = 3t^2 - 1$

$y1(t) = t^2$

$y2(t) = t^{-1}$

However when I attempt to do this I find that they do not satisfy, what am I doing wrong here? I start by differentiating y1

$y1(t) = t^2$

$y1'(t) = 2t$

$y1''(t) = 2$

Use these to plug into the original equation

$t^2y'' - 2y = 3t^2 - 1$

$t^2(2) - 2(t^2) = 3t^2 - 1$

$0 = 3t^2 - 1$

I get similar results doing the same thing with y2(t).

Comment: It asks for the "homogenous" equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that the given functions,

$$ y_1(t)=t^2$$

$$y_2(t)=\frac{1}{t}$$

Not that these two solutions are linearly independent of each other.

Are solution to the homogeneous equation.

Given that the second order non-homogeneous differential equation is

$$t^2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-2y=3t^2-1$$

To make it into homogeneous form which is

$$a_0(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_2(x)y=0$$

The homogeneous form of the differential equation is

$$t^2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-2y=0$$

To show that $y_1(t)$ is a solution to the differential equation, we just need to differentiate and plug into the homogeneous differential equation.

$$y=t^2$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=2t$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=2$$

$$t^2(2)-2(t^2)=0$$

Which is true

To show that $y_2(t)$ is a solution we then have

$$y=\frac{1}{t}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{1}{t^2}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{2}{t^3}$$

And plug it in

$$t^2(\frac{2}{t^3})-2(\frac{1}{t})=0$$

$$\frac{2}{t}-\frac{2}{t}=0$$

Which is also true.

The above is what you need to do to show that they are solutions to the homogeneous form of the differential equation.

Sometimes, $y_1(t)$ & $y_2(t)$ are called complementary solutions to the non-homogeneous differential equation.

Comments
In your question you are asked to solved homogeneous differential equation. However, you are solving the non-homogeneous differential equation and obviously it won't work.

Comment: Much thanks to your sir!

Comment: You are welcome and no problem!